# OAuth Authorized Access Token question for Java

Tags: java, blackberry, oauth, token, netflix

I am developing an OAuth library to be used by BlackBerry mobile devices to connect to Netflix. I have successfully negotiated the request token and the access token. I have received the authorized token, the token secret, and the encrypted subscriber ID.

Encrypted subscriber ID:

```
T1BlCJtdcWMuF6gJEfue96_W.kZ_gW81h59KqLEfT1AzE-
```

Authorized Token: `T1U.wMxbvP.KCdxGpqmfERA0y3BKEuyhYIljMF5W1k0iXD9j.2qDMw7NjoaOnG40UXESpqPk37gJbBlB1Ve.uatw--`

I am now having trouble using the subscriber ID and the authorized token to retrieve the user information from Netflix. Does the authorized token look correct? It seems a little off to me as compared to the request token and unauthorized token....

I would appreciate any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those seem correct to me. Have you compared the request you're making to the one on http://developer.netflix.com/walkthrough? Are you making sure to use the oauth_token_secret returned from requesting the access_token (step 4 in the walkthrough), and not the one you got from request_token (step 1 in the walkthrough)?